# Python instance from class not initiating

Tags: python, class

I'm learning python and currently working on exercises on classes. With this one, I can't figure out what's wrong. The instructions are:

Write a class named Pets with the following attributes:

- name
- type
- age

It should have an `__init__` method creating these attributes and should also have the following methods:

- set_name to assign a value to name
- set_type to assign a value to type
- set_age to assign a value to age
- get_name to return the value of name
- get_type to return the value of type
- get_age to return the value of age

Then, write a program that initiates an object and prompts the user to input name, type and age. Use the methods of the object to find the name, type, and age of the pet and show it on the screen.

This is the code I've written:

```
class Pet():

    def __init__(self, name, type, age):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.age = age

    def set_name(self):
        name = input("Type in the pet's name: ")

    def set_type(self):
        type = input("Type in the pet's type: ")

    def set_age(self):
        age = int(input("Type in the pet's age: "))

    def get_name(set_name):
        return set_name

    def get_type(set_type):
        return set_type

    def get_age(set_age):
        return set_age

 pet = Pet(set_name, set_type, set_age)
```

I get a NameError: name 'set_name' is not defined. I've tried different arguments when creating the object from the Pet class.

How should I define methods and arguments to get this to work?

Comment: The instructions say to set the name etc from a _value_. The method shouldn't call `input`. The code outside the class should first gather the name, type, and age from the user, and then use those values to create a Pet.

Comment: FWIW, in Python we don't normally use setter & getter methods for simple attribute access. My guess is that book was originally written for another language like Java, and has been adapted to Python.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring, makes sense now. And noted about the setter & getter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the command:

```
pet = Pet(set_name, set_type, set_age)
```

Although set_name, set_type and set_age are methods of your class, those are *interpreted* as variables, and they haven't yet been initialized.

Try refactoring your code to something like:

```
name = 'Ted'
type = 'Bear'
age = 5

pet = Pet(name, type, age)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pet = Pet(set_name, set_type, set_age)`
You never define what the global variable `set_name`, `set_type` and `set_age`. If they are strings, use `pet = Pet("set_name", "set_type", "set_age")`.

Then this is wrong:
`    def get_name(set_name):
        return set_name

```
def get_type(set_type):
    return set_type

def get_age(set_age):
    return set_age`
```

The first argument of a method should be `self`, so what you are returning is actually the object itself.

`def set_name(self):
        name = input("Type in the pet's name: ")`

Is also wrong, you are storing the result of the input inside a temporary variable.

This is more like a proper class (although I would use properties instead of explicit setters/getters):

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, type, age):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.age = age

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_type(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

 pet = Pet("Foo", "cat", 4)
```